# Rspec: Failure/Error: expect(qbase).to have_received(:with_user_id).with(1)

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

How do I detect if the instance of CarQuery has called a method with a specific parameter? (I assume that is my issue, but please tell me if I am wrong).

Is there a better way to test this?

#### Error

```
Search#base_filters should call with_limit method on query_object when user_id is passed in
     Failure/Error: expect(qbase).to have_received(:with_user_id).with(1)

       (Double "CarQuery").with_user_id(1)
           expected: 1 time with arguments: (1)
           received: 0 times
```

#### Search Query

```
class Search
  def self.call(current_user, params)
    new(current_user, params).call
  end

  def initialize(current_user, params)
    @params = params
    @current_user = current_user
  end

  def call
    base_filters(CarQuery.new(@current_user)).relation
  end

  private

  def base_filters(query_object)
    query_object.with_user_id(@params[:user_id]) if @params[:user_id].present?
    query_object
  end
end
```

#### Rspec Test

```
RSpec.describe Search, type: :model do
  describe "#base_filters" do
    it "should call with_limit method on query_object when user_id is passed in" do

      current_user = create(:user)
      qbase =spy('CarQuery')
      expect(qbase).to have_received(:with_user_id).with(1)
      Search.call(current_user, {user_id: 1})
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved with Dependency Injection

If there is a better solution, please post it.

#### Search Query

```
class Search
  def self.call(current_user, params, query_object_override = nil)
    new(current_user, params, query_object_override).call
  end

  def initialize(current_user, params, query_object_override = nil)
    @params = params
    @current_user = current_user
    @query_object = query_object_override
  end

  def call
    base_filters(query_object).relation
  end

  private

  def query_object
    @query_object ||= CarQuery.new(@current_user)
  end

  def base_filters(query_object)
    query_object.with_user_id(@params[:user_id]) if @params[:user_id].present?
    query_object
  end
end
```

#### Rspec Test

```
RSpec.describe Search, type: :model do
  describe "#base_filters" do
    it "should call with_user_id method on query_object when user_id is passed in" do

      current_user = create(:user)
      query_object = spy('CarQuery')
      Search.call(current_user, {user_id: 1}, query_object)
      expect(query_object).to have_received(:with_user_id )
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: fantastic! This is exactly right - you have have to publicly expose it in order to test it the way you want to.

Answer (score 0):

### Must call method on spy for it to work

If you are using a spy, then you need to call the method on it and then test whether the method has been received. See the rspec documentation on spies [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies). Or alternatively you can use a double. They are both similar, but you can't expect a double to work exactly like a spy.

```
RSpec.describe Search, type: :model do
  describe "#base_filters" do
    it "should call with_limit method on query_object when user_id is passed in" do
      current_user = create(:user)
      qbase =spy('CarQuery')
      qbase.with_user_id(1) # <-------- you need to add this line here first
      ## but does qbase even have a method called 'with_user_id'? if not,
      ## it will still fail
      expect(qbase).to have_received(:with_user_id).with(1) 
      # If you don't add the line above, of course it will fail, 
      ## you haven't sent qbase any messages! It won't work otherwise.
      ## I'm not sure what the line below is doing in relation to your tests?
      Search.call(current_user, {user_id: 1})
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Search.call calls the CarQuery.new().with_user_id, please see code

Comment: @user2012677 yes, Search.call calls CarQuery, but your test will never pass:  you need to set up the spy correctly, and the expectations correctly.

Comment: if you know how, please help

Comment: @user2012677 the problem is that you're not understanding how tests and spies should be set up - please ready the link i posted above. I would restructure the class in order to do it. You cannot test it directly because you have not publicly exposed it.

Comment: I read the page you posted before I posted and read it again. I still do not know the solution, hence why I posted. I am not testing it directly.. `.call` is calling base_filters, which calls the method.